Filter and sort data with multiple column & row criteria and match corresponding data to it with fixed and flexible return_arrays



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q




1
Product

Shop

2023-S
2023-M

2024-S
2024-M

Type








2



















3







500











4


P-Line_A









Step1






5
Prod_A

shop3

80
2%

500
22%

t1

ColCrit1
ColCrit2
ColCrit3




6
Prod_B

shop2

320
23%

180
60%

t1

Prod_D
shop1
t3




7
Prod_B

shop1

90
8%

300
36%

t2

Prod_G
shop3
t4




8
Prod_C

shop3

500
15%

657
16%

t1


shop4





9
Prod_D

shop1

160
17%

500
15%

t3








10
Prod_D

shop1

500
30%

600
8%

t3

rowCrit






11
Prod_D

shop1

130
4%

300
4%

t3

2024-S






12
Total



1810


3037











13



















14







600




Step2






15







300




l_array
r_array3
r_array4




16


P-Line_B









2024-S
Shop
2023-S




17
Prod_E

shop2

75
10%

450
10%

t1








18
Prod_F

shop4

60
8%

370
4%

t2








19
Prod_F

shop1

500
11%

850
4%

t2

Step3






20
Prod_G

shop3

350
8%

150
15%

t3

Rows
Start





21
Prod_G

shop3

60
47%

600
7%

t4

10
2





22
Prod_G

shop4

90
25%

830
35%

t4








23
Prod_G

shop2

390
9%

325
13%

t1








24
Prod_G

shop3

90
30%

300
9%

t3

Step4






25
Prod_G

shop4

90
5%

300
12%

t3

Product
Type
Shop
2023-M
2024-S


26
Prod_G

shop4

120
24%

300
24%

t4

Prod_D
t3
shop1
500
600


27
Prod_G

shop4

135
35%

480
17%

t4

Prod_G
t4
shop3
60
600


28
Prod_H

shop2

935
27%

230
16%

t1

Prod_D
t3
shop1
160
500


29
Prod_I

shop3

134
18%

600
42%

t2

Prod_G
t4
shop4
135
480


30
Total



3029


5785




Prod_D
t3
shop1
130
300


31












Prod_G
t3
shop3
90
300


32












Prod_G
t3
shop4
90
300


33












Prod_G
t4
shop4
120
300


34












Prod_G
t3
shop3
350
150


35



















36





















Target
The final Output is Range M26:Q34 which is a descending list based on the lookup_array in Cell M16 and multiple column and row filters (Range M6:M8, Range N6:O8, Range O6:O8 and Cell M11) and selected positions in the rank based on Cell M21 and Cell N21.
To get this list the following steps are required: 
(You can also see the steps in the table in Column M so it is easier to follow the instructions)

Define multiple column criteria in Range M6:O6 and a row criteria in Cell M11. These criteria are all AND criteria. After filtering the list it should be sorted descending.
Based on Step1 you will have a descending list fulfilling the column and row criteria. For this list the corresponding values based on ret_array3 in Cell N16 and ret_array4  in Cell O16 should be added.  (Note: lookup_array = rowCrit --> Cell M16 = Cell M11) 


In contrast to this question the first two columns Product and Type are fixed which means they should always appear by default.  Only the columns after these are flexible based on the inputs in Cell N16 and Cell O16.  It should be easily possible to chain even more ret_arrays to the formula. 


From the list in Step2 only the values that are ranked in positions based on Cell M21 and Cell N21 should be displayed.  In this case the 10 positions after the 1st position.
After Step1-3 in Step4 the final list should appear.


How do I need to modify the formula from this question to make it work?
=LET(
    _a, COUNTIF(M6:M8,A1:A31)+AND(M6:M8=""),
    _b, COUNTIF(N6:N8,C1:C31)+AND(N6:N8=""),
    _c, COUNTIF(O6:O8,K1:K31)+AND(O6:O8=""),
    _d, TOROW(HSTACK(N16,O16,M16),1),
    _e, CHOOSECOLS(A1:K31,XMATCH(_d,A1:K1)),
    _f, COLUMNS(_d),
    _g, SORT(FILTER(HSTACK(_e,FILTER(A1:K31,A1:K1=M11,"")),_a*_b*_c,""),_f+1,-1),
    VSTACK(_d, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(INDEX(_g,SEQUENCE(M21,,N21),SEQUENCE(,_f)),2),_f)))


Column 2023-M will be percentage and btw this is what you need to enter: TOROW(HSTACK("Product","Type",N16,O16,M16),1)

Changed it to 2023-S

One more, Product D -- Type t3 --> Shop 1 shown twice. Should nt be once 160 and another 130?

Changet it as well.

Try the following formula:


=LET(
    _a, COUNTIF(M6:M8,A1:A31)+AND(M6:M8=""),
    _b, COUNTIF(N6:N8,C1:C31)+AND(N6:N8=""),
    _c, COUNTIF(O6:O8,K1:K31)+AND(O6:O8=""),
    _d, TOROW(HSTACK("Product","Type",N16,O16,M16),1),
    _e, CHOOSECOLS(A1:K31,XMATCH(_d,A1:K1)),
    _f, COLUMNS(_d),
    _g, SORT(FILTER(HSTACK(_e,FILTER(A1:K31,A1:K1=M11,"")),_a*_b*_c,""),_f+1,-1),
    VSTACK(_d, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(INDEX(_g,SEQUENCE(M21,,N21),SEQUENCE(,_f)),2),_f)))



Is there also way to do it when there is no column header so it is fixed to Column A and Column C?

Sorry I am not able to understand, can you please explain further.

But your goal is to have fixed columns for Products and Type right, then why A To C?

Your solution works. It was more an additional question from me if there is an option without referring to the header of the column so the formula is independent from the header name and is based on the column itself.

I can also open separate question for it but not sure if needed if the solution is easy and you can add to your answer here.

Let me think, what you are tying to say. I will update

It means in my example instead of referring to "Product" and "Type" you refer to Column A and Column K. I think it is a bit confusing in this example because it is better to have an example where it would refer to Column A and Column C and the "Type" and "2023-M" are the flexible return_arrays. I will open a new question for it later.

@Michi I understand now, then why not just refer the column headers cell like this way: TOROW(HSTACK(A1,K1,N16,O16,M16),1)
